# Mutationobserver not fired when innerhtml changed by javascript code

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have a MutationObserver that observe an element with id `shipping_cost` and fire function `updateTotal()` when the innerhtml of the element changed. The MutationObserver works when the innerHTML is changed from external source (such as inspect element). But when i change the innerHTML from inside javascript, MutationObserver did not get fired, where did i do wrong?

It can be seen in the code that at the end of the javascript, i tried to change innerhtml from inside javascript, but the innerhtml of element with id `total` did not change, which indicates that `updateTotal()` did not get fired.

However, the function `updateTotal()` get fired when i change the innerhtml using inspect element (in chrome: right click -> inspect). How do i fix this ?

```js
const subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
const shipping_cost = document.getElementById("shipping_cost");
const total = document.getElementById("total");
const price_loading_text = "Loading . . .";
shipping_cost.innerHTML = price_loading_text;
total.innerHTML = price_loading_text;
function updateTotal() {
    if(shipping_cost.innerHTML != price_loading_text) {
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(subtotal.innerHTML) + parseInt(shipping_cost.innerHTML);
    } else {
        total.innerHTML = price_loading_text;
    }
}
updateTotal();

observer = new MutationObserver(updateTotal);

observer.observe(shipping_cost, {
attributes: false,
childList: false,
subtree: true,
characterData: true});

shipping_cost.innerHTML = "100";
```

```html
<p>Subtotal: <span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">9999</span></p>
<p>Shipping_cost: <span id="shipping_cost" class="shipping_cost"></span></p>
<p>Total: <span id="total" class="total"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
shipping_cost.innerHTML = "100";
```

modifies the element's children - specifically, it removes all of its existing children from the DOM and then inserts a new text node as a child. That should make it intuitive that you need not

```
childList: false,
```

but instead

```
childList: true,
```

for changes to the children to be seen.

```js
const subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
const shipping_cost = document.getElementById("shipping_cost");
const total = document.getElementById("total");
const price_loading_text = "Loading . . .";
shipping_cost.innerHTML = price_loading_text;
total.innerHTML = price_loading_text;

function updateTotal() {
  if (shipping_cost.innerHTML != price_loading_text) {
    total.innerHTML = parseFloat(subtotal.innerHTML) + parseInt(shipping_cost.innerHTML);
  } else {
    total.innerHTML = price_loading_text;
  }
}
updateTotal();

observer = new MutationObserver(updateTotal);

observer.observe(shipping_cost, {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
});

shipping_cost.innerHTML = "100";
```

```html
<p>Subtotal: <span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">9999</span></p>
<p>Shipping_cost: <span id="shipping_cost" class="shipping_cost"></span></p>
<p>Total: <span id="total" class="total"></span></p>
```

That said, I'd recommend only using an observer when code *you have no control over* makes a mutation to the DOM. If you have control over all the code in the app, it's usually far easier to just call the desired function after changing the DOM. For example, don't do

```
shipping_cost.innerHTML = "100";
```

but do

```
const updateShippingCost = (newCost) => {
  shipping_cost.innerHTML = newCost;
  total.innerHTML = Number(subtotal.innerHTML) + newCost;
};
updateShippingCost(100);
```

Comment: But i wonder what is the difference between changing innerhtml from javascript and changing innerhtml from inspect element? why they are fundamentally different in the eye of MutationObserver?

Comment: You can log the MutationRecord inside `updateTotal` to see. It appears that changing it from the Elements tab results in a `characterData` change. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData Perhaps the node is *changed* instead of *removed* (`.innerHTML` will remove and replace the node, in comparison)